# Record only capture the main window using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, replaykit

The ReplayKit recording will only capture the main window of your application. When designing for screen recording, you can place any UI elements in a separate UIWindow object. Although applications typically only have one UIWindow, iOS allows many windows. A UIWindow requires a .rootViewController to provide content.

How do I create another UIWindow in SwiftUI?

According to this [article](https://img.ly/blog/record-screen-with-swift-replaykit/) it is possible to implement it on UIKit.

[main view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYEdz.png)
[controls UIWindow and player UIWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dXyY.png)

I tried adding a new UIWindow like this and it didn't work.

```
extension UIApplication {
    
    var windowScene: UIWindowScene? {
        // Get connected scenes
        return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            // Keep only active scenes, onscreen and visible to the user
            .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            // Keep only the first `UIWindowScene`
            .first(where: { $0 is UIWindowScene })
            // Get its associated windows
            .flatMap({ $0 as? UIWindowScene })
    }
    
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Open New Window") {
                if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.windowScene {
                    let newWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                    newWindow.windowScene = windowScene
                    newWindow.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView:  Text("This is another view!"))
                    newWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try the same technique just interface with swiftui using a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, the recommended approach for managing multiple windows is by using the @State property wrapper and WindowGroup structure provided by the SwiftUI framework. Here's an example of how you can create and manage multiple windows in SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct YourApp: App {
    @State private var playerWindow: UIWindow?
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onAppear {
                    createPlayerWindow()
                }
        }
        .onChange(of: playerWindow) { newPlayerWindow in
            if let window = newPlayerWindow {
                // Handle the appearance or dismissal of the player window
                window.isHidden = false
            } else {
                // Player window dismissed
                // Clean up resources or perform any necessary actions
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func createPlayerWindow() {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: PlayerView())
        
        // Configure any additional window properties if needed
        
        playerWindow = window
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Main Content View")
    }
}

struct PlayerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Player View")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I need. Check out the [article](https://img.ly/blog/record-screen-with-swift-replaykit/). Main uiwindow with and above the uiwindow with screen recording controls. As a result, when you record, you will only get a view of the main uiwindow without the controls uiwindow.

Comment: The user should see everything and record only the content without ui elements